# System Time is Wrong in Windows 7 after dual booting Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, time

After installing Ubuntu, the time in my Windows 7 is wrong on start up. Even after updating the time in the Internet Time Settings manually, it still reverts back to the incorrect time after a while.

This [fix](http://www.comptalks.com/how-to-fix-incorrect-time-display-in-Windows-when-dual-booting-with-Linux-or-OS-x/) seems to do the job for most people but I does not work for me. The time in Ubuntu is correct.

I've searched high and low for a solution?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that Linux generally prefers to keep the BIOS clock in UTC, whereas Windows prefers to keep it in local time.  It may be easier to get Ubuntu to keep it in local time than to get Windows to keep it in UTC, even though UTC is probably Better.  [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) page (towards the bottom) gives instructions for both; it looks like the Windows-side fix is probably the same as what you've already tried, but hopefully the Ubuntu-side one will work.